# Test if a certain method is called during an object initialization Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a superclass that calls a certain independent method during its initialization. Something like

```
class MasterClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if type(self).__name__ == "SpecificClass":
            call_a_module_method()
```

I want to test that a subclass of this class called `SpecificClass` will get `call_a_module_method` method called.

Comment: `isinstance` should work: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but I am looking for a way to test that `call_a_module_method` will be called.

Comment: What does the method do? Can you check the results of its operation? Is this for a test? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If the method manipulates any data you could test for the expected changes in data

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but your design is wrong. Base classes shouldn't know about there subclasses, so the call to `call_a_module_method` should be in `SpecificClass.__init__`, not in `MasterClass.__init__`.

Comment: I totally agree. It was a design issue. The actual code is `if type(self).__name__ != "SpecificClass":`
We realized later we didn't want to call the method if the class was  `SpecificClass`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kevin Lee adviced you can use `isinstance` check or, if for some other reasons you do not want to directly check class in your tests, the option is to use [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock):

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

 @patch('module_name.call_a_module_method')
 def test_method_called(self, mock):
     instance = SpecificClass()
     self.assertTrue(mock.called)
```